# How to replace/shuffle one column with another in R?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I was wondering that is there way to shuffle two columns in matrix?
I have a matrix of 800 x 12. I want to replace column 1 by column 2 and column 2 by column 1. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you just wanting to reorder the columns? e.g. `m <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2); m[, c(2,1)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- matrix(1:15,5,3) # create 5x3 matrix
x[,c(1,2)] <- x[,c(2,1)] # exchange columns 1 and 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
before <- data.frame(c1=1:3, c2=4:6)
after <- before[,c("c2", "c1")]
```

Comment: The OP says they're using a matrix